# Opening a SwipeView using a custom renderer UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, shared-libraries, xamarin.uwp, swipeview

I try since few days to find a way to provoke sliding, opening of a Xamarin Forms SwipeView using the mouse.   I Found the solution in the picture here and it work at least i have the event happening and interpreting is right.    The problem is that i have the console message, but it it won't open.   I did interface, Asbstract base class and nothing allow me to open the swipe.   Anybody have an idea?
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SwipeView), typeof(SwipeViewRendererUWP))]

```
    public class SwipeViewRendererUWP : SwipeViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SwipeView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia;
            Control.ManipulationDelta += Control_ManipulationDelta;
            Control.ManipulationCompleted += Control_ManipulationCompleted;
            Control.ManipulationStarted += Control_ManipulationStarted;
            Control.PointerPressed += Control_PointerPressed;
            Control.PointerReleased += Control_PointerReleased;
        }
    }

    private void Control_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Control_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleasePointerCaptures();
    }

    private void Control_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
    }

    private bool _isSwiped;

    private void Control_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Server.ConsoleDebug("Swipe Ended");
        _isSwiped = false;
    }

    private void Control_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsInertial && !_isSwiped)
        {
            var swipedDistance = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;

            if (Math.Abs(swipedDistance) <= 2) return;
            {
                if (swipedDistance > 0)
                {
                    
                    Element.Open(OpenSwipeItem.LeftItems);
                    Server.ConsoleDebug("left swipe");
                }
                else
                {
                    Element.Open(OpenSwipeItem.RightItems);
                    Server.ConsoleDebug("right swipe");
                }

                _isSwiped = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please do NOT post code as images!!!

Comment: how can i change it?

Comment: edit your question and paste and format your code using markdown